# Risks of using unsafeperformIO on randomIO

Tags: haskell, random, unsafe-perform-io

I am creating a Haskell application that generates a random number on an infinite loop (only when requested by a client). However, I should only use pure functions for that purpose. Is it safe to wrap `randomIO` with `unsafeperformIO` without any drastic stability or performance risk?

Comment: You should use [`random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#v:random) or [`randomR`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#v:randomR) in pure code.

Comment: NO!  You might be able to justify `unsafeInterleaveIO` but nothing random is pure!

Comment: @PhilipJF: "nothing random is pure"? I'd say things like (not–in-place) quicksort with random pivot are pure algorithms allright: the randomness can't be observed from the outside except through performance variations, which only have any meaning in the `IO` monad anyway.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Good example!

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Well, that quicksort itself isn't random then, is it? It's as pure as `runST`, there's just no easy way to enforce it the way `ST` does. The random values are still "locally" impure, though.

Comment: I question the need to use `unsafePerformIO` at all.  Why do you say that you must only use pure functions?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use the `Rand` monad or its [`RandT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html#t:RandT) transformer. This way you can make your code pure, without needing to use `IO` or to carry the random state around all the time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any use of `unsafePerformIO` should be justified by a proof that the resulting value is still pure. The rigour of the proof is up to you and the importance of the work. For example, this pathetic use `unsafePerformIO` and `randomIO` should be safe, because you can *prove* that when `slowTrue` returns anything, it will return `True`.

```
import System.Random
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Data.Int

slowTrue = unsafePerformIO $ go
  where
    go = do
        x1 <- randomIO
        x2 <- randomIO
        if ((x1 :: Int16) == x2) then return True else go
```

The following tempting definition of a global, possibly random variables is not safe:

```
rand :: Bool -> Int
rand True = unsafePerformIO randomIO 
rand False = 0
```

The problem is that the same expression will now yield different values:

```
main = do
    print (rand True)
    print (rand True)
```

prints here:

```
-7203223557365007318
-7726744474749938542
```

(at least when compiled without optimizations – but that just stresses the fragility of inappropriate use of `unsafePerformIO`).

Comment: That's an interesting question. Top level definition `unknown = unsafePerformIO randomIO` is actually safe if compiler will evaluate body of `unknown` only once. But I'm pretty sure that compiler have rights to inline it and/or calculate many times.

Comment: I had that as my example first, but I could not tickle GHC enough to make that actually observable, therefore this example.

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating a Haskell application that generates a random number on an infinite loop (only when requested by a client). However, I should only use pure functions for that purpose. Is it safe to wrap randomIO with unsafeperformIO without any drastic stability or performance risk?

Aside from performance (no risk) or stability (small risk), consider also the fact that you are writing non-canonical Haskell for no good reason. Your code will be difficult for anyone else to maintain if you take this approach.